# Why does foldBack not execute the same side-effects that fold does?

Tags: f#, fold

I was working through the answers to [Example of the difference between List.fold and List.foldBack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27935999/2314532) trying to get my head around the difference between `fold` and `foldBack`. I understand the difference in application order now, but there's a difference in side-effects that I don't understand.

I used [`List.fold`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353894.aspx) and [`List.foldBack`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353846.aspx) for my testing. My accumulator functions that were basically equivalent to `::`, so that accumulation order would matter. The accumulator functions I used were as follows:

```
let f acc x =
  // printfn "Folding %A into %A" x acc  // Side-effect!
  x :: acc

let f2 x acc =
  // printfn "Folding %A into %A" x acc  // Side-effect!
  x :: acc
```

I understand from the F# reference that:

```
List.fold f [] [1; 2; 3; 4; 5] = (f (f (f (f (f [] 1) 2) 3) 4) 5)
```

and:

```
List.foldBack f2 [] [1; 2; 3; 4; 5] = (f2 1 (f2 2 (f2 3 (f2 4 (f2 5 [])))))
```

should both return `true`, and they do. Great, I thought; I understand how it works. But just to make sure, I uncommented the side-effect lines from `f` and `f2` and ran `List.fold f` and `List.foldBack f2` again. Result of `List.fold f [] [1; 2; 3; 4; 5]` with the `printfn` line uncommented:

```
Folding 1 into []
Folding 2 into [1]
Folding 3 into [2; 1]
Folding 4 into [3; 2; 1]
Folding 5 into [4; 3; 2; 1]
val it : bool = true
```

Result of `List.foldBack f2 [] [1; 2; 3; 4; 5]` with the `printfn` line uncommented:

```
val it : bool = true
```

I was expecting "Folding N into [list]" to show up in both cases. But `List.fold` executed the side effects of its accumulator function, and `List.foldBack` did not.

**Why is there a difference in side-effect execution between the two forms of `fold`?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the arguments in the wrong order.

It should be

```
> List.foldBack f2  [1; 2; 3; 4; 5] [];;
Folding 5 into []
Folding 4 into [5]
Folding 3 into [4; 5]
Folding 2 into [3; 4; 5]
Folding 1 into [2; 3; 4; 5]
val it : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
```

Comment: Oh, I see it now. That makes more sense -- that way `foldBack` takes its arguments in the same order that its accumulator function expects (input list first in `foldBack`, input item first in accumulator function).

Such a simple thing to miss. Thanks!

Comment: That is made that way in order to avoid mistakes: usually your accumulator and your list would be of different types, and so if you mess up the order of the arguments, it won't compile.