# Understanding side effects with monadic traversal

Tags: functional-programming, f#, monads, traversal, fsharpx

I am trying to properly understand how side effects work when traversing a list in F# using monadic style, following Scott's guide [here](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/elevated-world-4/)

I have an AsyncSeq of items, and a side-effecting function that can return a Result<'a,'b> (it is saving the items to disk).

I get the general idea - split the head and tail, apply the func to the head. If it returns Ok then recurse through the tail, doing the same thing. If an Error is returned at any point then short circuit and return it.

I also get why Scott's ultimate solution uses foldBack rather than fold - it keeps the output list in the same order as the input as each processed item is prepended to the previous.

I can also follow the logic:

- The result from the list's last item (processed first as we are using foldback) will be passed as the accumulator to the next item.
- If it is an Error and the next item is Ok, the next item is discarded.
- If the next item is an Error, it replaces any previous results and becomes the accumulator.
- That means by the time you have recursed over the entire list from right to left and ended up at the start, you either have an Ok of all of the results in the correct order or the most recent Error (which would have been the first to occur if we had gone left to right).

**The thing that confuses me is that surely, since we are starting at the end of the list, all side effects of processing every item will take place, even if we only get back the last Error that was created?**

This seems to be confirmed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35218872/why-does-foldback-not-execute-the-same-side-effects-that-fold-does?rq=1) as the print output starts with [5], then [4,5], then [3,4,5] etc.

The thing that confuses me is that this *isn't* what I see happening when I use [AsyncSeq.traverseChoiceAsync](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpx.Async/blob/4fd12b31c2f03ab9e68cdfaac0b20b859d1ccb10/src/FSharpx.Async/AsyncSeq.fs) from the FSharpx lib (which I wrapped to process Result instead of Choice). I see side effects happening from left to right, stopping on the first error, which is what I want to happen.

It also looks like Scott's non-tail recursive version (which doesn't use foldBack and just recurses over the list) goes from left to right? The same goes for the AsyncSeq version. That would explain why I see it short circuit on the first error but surely if it completes Ok then the output items would be reversed, which is why we normally use foldback?

I feel I am misunderstanding or misreading something obvious! Could someone please explain it to me? :)

**Edit:**
rmunn has given a really great comprehensive explanation of the AsyncSeq traversal below. The TLDR was that

- Scott's initial implementation and the AsyncSeq traverse both *do* go from left to right as I thought and so only process until they hit an error
- they keep their contents in order by prepending the head to the processed tail rather than prepending each processed result to the previous (which is what the built in F# fold does).
- foldback would keep things in order but would indeed execute every case (which could take forever with an async seq)

Comment: Async sequences support exceptions. I think you can make your life a lot easier just by throwing and catching exceptions.

Comment: If it wasn't you suggesting that @Tomas I wouldn't have given it much thought but it is a good point, a traversal might be over engineering the code. I'm not sure though, I have set my seq up to pull from a paged API, then I map it from dtos to domain models, I join the pages into a single stream and then post to the database. That's a whole bunch of places that would need to start throwing instead of returning results. Traversing seemed a nice way to deal with it, but this is my first time using AsyncSeq and I just learnt traverse so maybe I am using a sledgehammer to crack a nut!

Comment: I guess it's hard to say what's best in general - the nice thing about using things like `Result` is that you can compose code in sophisticated ways (e.g. collect non-critical errors, but still continue running). Exceptions give you just one way of sequencing - if anything goes wrong, stop! If that's all you need, then I'd consider them - yeah, they're not type checked, but F# is not pure, so I think it's fine. And I often prefer the simplicity & readability you get by using built-in language features over the type safety benefits of more advanced (but somewhat ugly and complicated) methods.

Comment: Absolutely. I found using the applicative style of traversal makes form validation etc a breeze. I am also fond of using an asyncResult CE to sequence my workflows, so many of my functions return result types. I am just learning about event sourcing (EventStore is the paged API I am hitting) and obviously folding over event lists to create projections is a big part of that too. I can't imagine trying to implement it in an OO language. I use C# and F# together to make Xamarin apps for the most part so I am certainly not a purist, I just have fallen for FP's charms in a big way :)

Comment: I also have your Deep Dives book which is fantastic, thanks to you and the others for putting it together :)

Comment: Thanks! Although I did very little actual work on Deep Dives :-) all the praise goes to chapter authors!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty simple: `traverseChoiceAsync` isn't using `foldBack`. Yes, with `foldBack` the last item would be processed first, so that by the time you get to the first item and discover that its result is `Error` you'd have triggered the side effects of every item. Which is, I think, precisely why whoever wrote `traverseChoiceAsync` in FSharpx chose not to use `foldBack`, because they wanted to ensure that side effects would be triggered in order, and stop at the first `Error` (or, in the case of the `Choice` version of the function, the first `Choice2Of2` — but I'll pretend from this point on that that function was written to use the `Result` type.)

Let's look at the `traverseChoieAsync` function in the code you linked to, and read through it step-by-step. I'll also rewrite it to use `Result` instead of `Choice`, because the two types are basically identical in function but with different names in the DU, and it'll be a little easier to tell what's going on if the DU cases are called `Ok` and `Error` instead of `Choice1Of2` and `Choice2Of2`. Here's the original code:

```
let rec traverseChoiceAsync (f:'a -> Async<Choice<'b, 'e>>) (s:AsyncSeq<'a>) : Async<Choice<AsyncSeq<'b>, 'e>> = async {
  let! s = s
  match s with
  | Nil -> return Choice1Of2 (Nil |> async.Return)
  | Cons(a,tl) ->
    let! b = f a
    match b with
    | Choice1Of2 b -> 
      return! traverseChoiceAsync f tl |> Async.map (Choice.mapl (fun tl -> Cons(b, tl) |> async.Return))
    | Choice2Of2 e -> 
      return Choice2Of2 e }
```

And here's the original code rewritten to use `Result`. Note that it's a simple rename, and none of the logic needs to be changed:

```
let rec traverseResultAsync (f:'a -> Async<Result<'b, 'e>>) (s:AsyncSeq<'a>) : Async<Result<AsyncSeq<'b>, 'e>> = async {
  let! s = s
  match s with
  | Nil -> return Ok (Nil |> async.Return)
  | Cons(a,tl) ->
    let! b = f a
    match b with
    | Ok b -> 
      return! traverseChoiceAsync f tl |> Async.map (Result.map (fun tl -> Cons(b, tl) |> async.Return))
    | Error e -> 
      return Error e }
```

Now let's step through it. The whole function is wrapped inside an `async { }` block, so `let!` inside this function means "unwrap" in an async context (essentially, "await").

```
let! s = s
```

This takes the `s` parameter (of type `AsyncSeq<'a>`) and unwraps it, binding the result to a local name `s` that henceforth will shadow the original parameter. When you await the result of an `AsyncSeq`, what you get is the *first* element only, while the rest is still wrapped in an async that needs to be further awaited. You can see this by looking at the result of the `match` expression, or by looking at the definition of the `AsyncSeq` type:

```
type AsyncSeq<'T> = Async<AsyncSeqInner<'T>>

and AsyncSeqInner<'T> =
    | Nil
    | Cons of 'T * AsyncSeq<'T>
```

So when you do `let! x = s` when `s` is of type `AsyncSeq<'T>`, the value of `x` will either be `Nil` (when the sequence has run to its end) or it will be `Cons(head, tail)` where `head` is of type `'T` and `tail` is of type `AsyncSeq<'T>`.

So after this `let! s = s` line, our *local* name `s` now refers to an `AsyncSeqInner` type, which contains the head item of the sequence (or `Nil` if the sequence was empty), and the rest of the sequence is *still wrapped* in an `AsyncSeq` so it has yet to be evaluated (and, crucially, its side effects have not yet happened).

```
match s with
| Nil -> return Ok (Nil |> async.Return)
```

There's a lot happening in this line, so it'll take a bit of unpacking, but the gist is that if the input sequence `s` had `Nil` as its head, i.e. had reached its end, then that's not an error, and we return an empty sequence.

Now to unpack. The outer `return` is in an `async` keyword, so it takes the `Result` (whose value is `Ok something`) and turns it into an `Async<Result<something>>`. Remembering that the return type of the function is declared as `Async<Result<AsyncSeq>>`, the inner `something` is clearly an `AsyncSeq` type. So what's going on with that `Nil |> async.Return`? Well, `async` isn't an F# keyword, it's the name of an instance of `AsyncBuilder`. Inside a computation expression `foo { ... }`, `return x` is translated into `foo.Return(x)`. So calling `async.Return x` is just the same as writing `async { return x }`, except that it avoids nesting a computation expression inside *another* computation expression, which would be a little nasty to try and parse mentally (and I'm not 100% sure the F# compiler allows it syntactically). So `Nil |> async.Return` is `async.Return Nil` which means it produces a value of `Async<x>` where `x` is the type of the value `Nil`. And as we just saw, this `Nil` is a value of type `AsyncSeqInner`, so `Nil |> async.Return` produces an `Async<AsyncSeqInner>`. And another name for `Async<AsyncSeqInner>` is `AsyncSeq`. So this whole expression produces an `Async<Result<AsyncSeq>>` that has the meaning of "We're done here, there are no more items in the sequence, and there was no error".

Phew. Now for the next line:

```
  | Cons(a,tl) ->
```

Simple: if the next item in the `AsyncSeq` named `s` was a `Cons`, we deconstruct it so that the actual *item* is now called `a`, and the tail (another `AsyncSeq`) is called `tl`.

```
    let! b = f a
```

This calls `f` on the value we just got out of `s`, and then unwraps the `Async` part of `f`'s return value, so that `b` is now a `Result<'b, 'e>`.

```
    match b with
    | Ok b ->
```

More shadowed names. Inside *this* branch of the `match`, `b` now names a value of type `'b` rather than a `Result<'b, 'e>`.

```
      return! traverseResultAsync f tl |> Async.map (Result.map (fun tl -> Cons(b, tl) |> async.Return))
```

Hoo boy. That's too much to tackle at once. Let's write this as if the `|>` operators were lined up on separate lines, and then we'll go through each step one at a time. (Note that I've wrapped an extra pair of parentheses around this, just to clarify that it's the *final result* of this whole expression that will be passed to the `return!` keyword).

```
      return! (
          traverseResultAsync f tl
          |> Async.map (
              Result.map (
                  fun tl -> Cons(b, tl) |> async.Return)))
```

I'm going to tackle this expression from the inside out. The inner line is:

```
fun tl -> Cons(b, tl) |> async.Return
```

The `async.Return` thing we've already seen. This is a function that takes a tail (we don't currently know, or care, what's inside that tail, except that by the necessity of the type signature of `Cons` it must be an `AsyncSeq`) and turns it into an `AsyncSeq` that is `b` followed by the tail. I.e., this is like `b :: tl` in a list: it sticks `b` onto the *front* of the `AsyncSeq`.

One step out from that innermost expression is:

```
Result.map
```

Remember that the function `map` can be thought of in two ways: one is "take a function and run it against whatever is "inside" this wrapper". The other is "take a function that operates on `'T` and make it into a function that operates on `Wrapper<'T>`". (If you don't have both of those clear in your mind yet, https://sidburn.github.io/blog/2016/03/27/understanding-map is a pretty good article to help grok that concept). So what this is doing is taking a function of type `AsyncSeq -> AsyncSeq` and turning it into a function of type `Result<AsyncSeq> -> Result<AsyncSeq>`. Alternately, you could think of it as taking a `Result<tail>` and calling `fun tail -> ...` against that `tail` result, then re-wrapping the result of that function in a new `Result`. **Important:** Because this is using `Result.map` (`Choice.mapl` in the original) we know that if `tail` is an `Error` value (or if the `Choice` was a `Choice2Of2` in the original), the function will *not be called*. So if `traverseResultAsync` produces a result that starts with an `Error` value, it's going to produce an `<Async<Result<foo>>>` where the value of `Result<foo>` is an `Error`, and so the value of the tail will be discarded. Keep that in mind for later.

Okay, next step out.

```
Async.map
```

Here, we have a `Result<AsyncSeq> -> Result<AsyncSeq>` function produced by the inner expression, and this converts it to an `Async<Result<AsyncSeq>> -> Async<Result<AsyncSeq>>` function. We've just talked about this, so we don't need to go over how `map` works again. Just remember that the *effect* of this `Async<Result<AsyncSeq>> -> Async<Result<AsyncSeq>>` function that we've built up will be the following:

1. Await the outer `async`.
2. If the result is `Error`, return that `Error`.
3. If the result is `Ok tail`, produce an `Ok (Cons (b, tail))`.

Next line:

```
traverseResultAsync f tl
```

I probably should have started with this, because this will actually run *first*, and then its value will be passed into the `Async<Result<AsyncSeq>> -> Async<Result<AsyncSeq>>` function that we've just analysed.

So what this whole thing will do is to say "Okay, we took the first part of the `AsyncSeq` we were handed, and passed it to `f`, and `f` produced an `Ok` result with a value we're calling `b`. So now we need to process the *rest* of the sequence similarly, and then, *if* the rest of the sequence produces an `Ok` result, we'll stick `b` on the front of it and return an `Ok` sequence with contents `b :: tail`. BUT if the rest of the sequence produces an `Error`, we'll *throw away* the value of `b` and just return that `Error` unchanged."

```
return!
```

This just takes the result we just got (either an `Error` or an `Ok (b :: tail)`, already wrapped in an `Async`) and returns it unchanged. But note that the call to `traverseResultAsync` is **NOT** tail-recursive, because its value had to be passed into the `Async.map (...)` expression first.

And now we still have one more bit of `traverseResultAsync` to look at. Remember when I said "Keep that in mind for later"? Well, that time has arrived.

```
    | Error e -> 
      return Error e }
```

Here we're back in the `match b with` expression. If `b` was an `Error` result, then *no further recursive calls* are made, and the whole `traverseResultAsync` returns an `Async<Result>` where the `Result` value is `Error`. And if we were currently nested deep inside a recursion (i.e., we're in the `return! traverseResultAsync ...` expression), then our return value will be `Error`, which means the result of the "outer" call, as we've kept in mind, will also be `Error`, discarding any other `Ok` results that might have happened "before".

#### Conclusion

And so the effect of all of that is:

1. Step through the `AsyncSeq`, calling `f` on each item in turn.
2. The *first* time `f` returns `Error`, stop stepping through, throw away any previous `Ok` results, and return that `Error` as the result of the whole thing.
3. If `f` never returns `Error` and instead returns `Ok b` every time, return an `Ok` result that contains an `AsyncSeq` of all those `b` values, in their original order.

Why are they in their original order? Because the logic in the `Ok` case is:

1. If sequence was empty, return an empty sequence.
2. Split into head and tail.
3. Get value `b` from `f head`.
4. Process the tail.
5. Stick value `b` in *front* of the result of processing the tail.

So if we started with (conceptually) `[a1; a2; a3]`, which actually looks like `Cons (a1, Cons (a2, Cons (a3, Nil)))` we'll end up with `Cons (b1, Cons (b2, Cons (b3, Nil)))` which translates to the conceptual sequence `[b1; b2; b3]`.

Comment: Thanks @rmunn, that is a great and comprehensive answer. I did actually already understand 99% of it already, but I appreciate it will be great for other people coming to this. Personally, the key bits I needed were a.) I was right, the recursive func Scott shows and AsyncSeq *do* go left to right, which is what it looked like to me and b.) the reason we need foldback instead of fold is just that the internal implementation of fold would reverse the items, but when implementing ourselves we have control over how the append is done.

Answer (score 2):

See @rmunn's great answer above for the explanation. I just wanted to post a little helper for anyone that reads this in the future, it allows you to use the AsyncSeq traverse with Results instead of the old Choice type it was written with:

```
let traverseResultAsyncM (mapping : 'a -> Async<Result<'b,'c>>) source = 
    let mapping' = 
        mapping
        >> Async.map (function
            | Ok x -> Choice1Of2 x
            | Error e -> Choice2Of2 e)

    AsyncSeq.traverseChoiceAsync mapping' source
    |> Async.map (function
        | Choice1Of2 x -> Ok x
        | Choice2Of2 e -> Error e)
```

Also here is a version for non-async mappings:

```
let traverseResultM (mapping : 'a -> Result<'b,'c>) source = 
    let mapping' x = async { 
        return 
            mapping x
            |> function
            | Ok x -> Choice1Of2 x
            | Error e -> Choice2Of2 e
    }

    AsyncSeq.traverseChoiceAsync mapping' source
    |> Async.map (function
        | Choice1Of2 x -> Ok x
        | Choice2Of2 e -> Error e)
```